# Como esconder o ID de uma URL

Tags: php, funções

Tenho uma função que captura o ID da URL e faz a consulta na DB e retorna o valor na pagina, como fazer essa consulta sem aparecer a ID na URL?

Atualmente esta assim:

> https://dominio.com/nome-do-post/?id=9991

Como fazer para esconder o `?id=9991` da URL para fica apenas assim:

> https://dominio.com/nome-do-post/

vou deixa a função aqui, mas acho que a função em si não agrega nada a pergunta.

```
function protetor() {
    $conexao = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","protetor");
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $dados = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM download WHERE ID = $id");
    $download = mysqli_fetch_array($dados);
    if (!empty($id)) {
        echo $download['link'];
    } else {
        echo "Link de download não encontrado!";
    }
}
```

Comment: `nome-do-post` é um valor único para o registro? Para fazer o que quer, ele precisará ser único. Leia sobre *slug* e URLs amigáveis.

Comment: no caso eu adiciono o `?id=9991` apenas para a função saber o que ela tem que procurar na tabela, isso não faz parte do post, a duvida e como eu posso fazer a função detectar essa ID sem eu ter que adicionar ela no final da URL

Comment: Exatamente. Sem o id, a única informação será `nome-do-post`, então esse valor terá que ser suficiente para você achar o registro no banco.

Comment: não teria uma maneira de passa esse ID para ele ser capturado por um cookie e depois a função pegar diretamente do cookie? tipo, redirecionar o ID desse jeito, mas depois que a pagina capturar o ID ela dar um refresh e salva no cookie, sera que seria possível fazer isso?

Comment: E por que não fazer da maneira mais fácil (e correta)?

Comment: @Anderson sendo bem sincero com você, eu não faço ideia de como fazer isso, tipo, eu não sou familiarizado com essas regras do HTACCESS, mas obrigado de qualquer forma, vou tenta tirar proveito dessa informação.

Comment: No primeiro comentário eu te dei as dicas do que você precisa estudar. O htaccess é uma das formas utilizadas. Foque primeiro em entender o conceito, depois tente aplicá-lo. Se ir direto pro htaccess e tentar fazer sem entender o que está fazendo será uma péssima experiência.

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia!

Vc tem a opção de transmitir através de um POST ao invés de um GET

ex:

```
<input type="hidden" ....value="ID" />
```

Também pode compartilhar o dado por SESSION que é menos recomendado.

Comment: No momento  que for mudar de página vc pode dar um send no form enviando o dado pelo POST

Comment: E se acessar a URL direto? Será uma requisição GET, não POST. O que você sugeriu é gambiarra, usar uma ferramenta para uma finalidade bem distinta para qual foi projetada.

Comment: o que eu estou tentando fazer e um protetor simples, eu adicionei o `?id=9991` no final da URL, apenas para a função saber o que ela tem que procurar dentro da tabela, eu quero redirecionar vários IDs diferentes para essa pagina, mas sem ter que mostrar qual o ID

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss É meio vago dizer que seria uma gambiarra, visto que é uma ótima tratativa para dados que devem ser "ocultados". No caso, a página de destino deve possuir um controller para tratar essas situações

Comment: Não é vago. Você estaria submetendo formulários apenas para navegar entre páginas. Formulário não foi projetado para isso e usá-lo para tal é gambiarra. Imagina o usuário acessando a página pelo menu, que faz um POST enviando o ID, toda vez que ele recarregar a página o navegador irá solicitar se ele quer reenviar as informações. Se ele dizer que não, quebra o site porque não haverá ID. Ele também não poderá salvar nos favoritos, pois se acessar futuramente será uma requisição GET, sem o ID, não uma POST.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss entendi com o exemplo que passou e a sua solução no outro comentario. Creio que nesse caso o correto mesmo seria com slug (se ñ houver nomes repetidos).
Obrigado pelo esclarecimento